# How do I fix Caps lock / Printscreen keys also lowering brightness

Tags: keyboard, troubleshooting, bugs

I've been having this issue lately where whenever I hit Caps Lock or Print Screen, it works normally but also acts like I hit the lower brightness key. This only happens with these keys specifically, none of the rest of them are bugged like this. I'm not sure where to start with troubleshooting this. Is there a way I can remap these inputs to just be capslock and just be printscreen as normal instead of being this weird inconvenient macro? I should also note that this only happens on this laptop's built-in keyboard. When using a USB keyboard, neither key has this problem. I am running debian-stable 12 (bookworm) with the KDE Plasma desktop environment on an ASUS ProArt Studiobook laptop.